# Solve this math table

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image]

Transcription (cells with ■ do not exist in the image version of the grid and should not be filled)

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | + |  | - |  | = | 1 |
| - | ■ | + | ■ | + | ■ | ■ |
|  | x |  | - |  | = | 29 |
| - | ■ | x | ■ | - | ■ | ■ |
|  | x |  | - |  | = | -1 |
| = | ■ | = | ■ | = | ■ | ■ |
| -10 | ■ | 9 | ■ | 1 | ■ | ■ |

Here are the rules:  use 1-9 only once in the black cells. Order of operations matters.

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

> 3 2 4
>  5 7 6
>  8 1 9
>
>  I started off with the middle row, the left two numbers have to be above 30, so 8x4, 9x4, 7x5
>  Bottom middle usually was 1, so the top middle adds up with middle to 9
>  Left column was interesting. You had to have two numbers that weren't used yet that could get you to -10

Answer (score 4):

### 3 | 2 | 4

### 5 | 7 | 6

### 8 | 1 | 9

Trial and error, mostly.